# Probability problem about a card located in a wardrobe or in $1$ of $5$ drawers each of them have the same probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

> A card is either in a wardrobe with a probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ or in one of five drawers with the same probability each drawer.
> If we have opened four drawers, chosen at random, and the card is not there, what is the probability that it is in the fifth drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $W$ is the probability of the card being in the wardrobe, and $D$ is the probability of it being in the remaining drawer, we have
$$P(D\mid W\cup D)=\frac{P(D\cap(D\cup W))}{P(D\cup W)}=\frac{P(D)}{P(D\cup W)}=\frac{\frac{4}{25}}{\frac{9}{25}}=\frac49$$
One notes that this is the ratio of the original probabilities of being in that particular drawer to being in that drawer or the wardrobe.